# Forgot to preserve timestamp and mode during copy. How to restore?

Tags: ubuntu, backup

I copied my hard-disk to another one using `cp` and forgot to use the `-p` option. Now all the files have the date of copying as the creation date. Of course I discovered it too late when the original information was already destroyed. And I would like to have the original copy and modification dates and the original modes.

But I still got a backup. Is there a way to restore from the backup the creation and modification dates and mode and ownership of all files that have not changed since they were copied? Alternatively I could copy all files that have not changed since the date of the copy but as it concerns several terabytes this is a less attractive option.

Comment: Seen this serverfault answer? [Rsync : copying over timestamps only](https://serverfault.com/questions/344731/rsync-copying-over-timestamps-only)

Comment: Thanks! It seems to be the answer I need, except for skipping the files that have already been updated. Anyhow, I'll dive into `rsync`, this seems to have the options I need. I'll get back to you.